# angularjs $q.all for nested promises

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

Trying to get nested async REST requests in AngularJS (1.6), and then execute code when all requests have been completed.

I tried using `$q.all` but it seems this will not take into account the inner requests (the episode ones).

How do I modify the below example so that I can execute code when all requests have been completed?

```
// foreach series --> load series details & seasons, foreach season --> load episodes
// when all requests are completed: do something

var requests = []

// e.g. series = [1]
series.forEach(function(seriesId) {
    requests.push(loadSeriesDetails(seriesId).then(function(data) {
        console.log("received details for series "+seriesId)
        // e.g. {id:1, title:"show 1"}
    }))
    requests.push(loadSeasons(seriesId).then(function (data) {
        console.log("received seasons for series "+seriesId+": ", data.seasons.length)
        // e.g. [{id:11, title:"season 1"}, {id:12, title:"season 2"}]
        data.seasons.map(function(e) {return e.id}).forEach(function(seasonId) {
            requests.push(loadEpisodes(seasonId).then(function (data) {
                console.log("received episodes for season "+seasonId+": ", data.episodes.length)
                // e.g.
                // season 11: [{id:111, title:"episode 1-1-1"}, {id:112, title:"episode 1-1-2"}, {id:113, title:"episode 1-1-3"}]
                // season 12: [{id:121, title:"episode 1-2-1"}, {id:122, title:"episode 1-2-2"}]
            }))
        })
    }))
})

$q.all(requests).then(function(result) {
    console.log("*** all requests completed ***")
    console.log(result.length)
})
```

The example above would return 2 (1x `loadSeriesDetails`, 1x `loadSeasons`) instead of 4 (1x `loadSeriesDetails`, 1x `loadSeasons`, 2x `loadEpisodes`).

Suggestions? Thanks in advance!

**Update:** each of the is request functions is like:

```
loadSeriesDetails = function(id) {
  url = "..."+id

  return $http.get(url).then(
    function (result) {
      return result.data
    }, function (error) {
      ̶r̶e̶t̶u̶r̶n̶ ̶e̶r̶r̶o̶r̶ 
      throw error;
  });
}
```

Comment: JavaScript has an amazing thing called a [return statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return). To understand how to use it with promises, see [You're Missing the Point of Promises](https://blog.domenic.me/youre-missing-the-point-of-promises/).

Comment: Not sure I understand your comment. The promise functions have returns (I have updated the question to show an example of one). Don't think the .then(...) callback function needs a return. Do you have an example of what it should look like?

Comment: To avoid **converting** a rejected promise to a fulfulled promise, use a [throw statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw) in the rejection handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `requests` array should have all of the promises that need to be resolved when you pass it to `$q.all`. Currently you are adding your promises for `loadEpisodes` to `requests` after earlier promises resolve.

You can break this up so that the inner section returns its own `$.q.all`, which will become chained:

```
    var requests = [];

    series.forEach(function (seriesId) {
        requests.push(loadSeriesDetails(seriesId).then(function (data) {
            console.log("received details for series " + seriesId);
            return data;
        }));

        requests.push(loadSeasons(seriesId).then(function (data) {
            console.log("received seasons for series " + seriesId + ": ", data.seasons.length);
            return loadAllEpisodes(data.seasons);
        }));
    });

    function loadAllEpisodes(seasons) {
        var requests = seasons.map(function (season) {
            return loadEpisodes(season.id).then(function (data) {
                console.log("received episodes for season " + season.id + ": ", data.episodes.length);
                return data;
            });
        });

        return $q.all(requests);
    }

    q.all(requests).then(function(result) {
        console.log("*** all requests completed ***");
        console.log(result.length);
    });
```

Note that in your example you'll still only see 2 results in the final array that is returned from the outer `$q.all`, because you're getting the results from the last promise of each chain. So you may want to adjust your return statements so they group information the way you need it.

Comment: Thanks Frank, this indeed was the solution. I will add a variation of the answer, which requires fewer modifications.

Comment: @georgeawg Thanks for the edit. The original question didn't return results so I just left it that way, but you're right, the results should be returned if needed.

Comment: I want to encourage readers to **always return results** from a function. It makes those functions more useful, more versatile, easier to debug, easier to test, and easier to maintain.

Answer (score 3):

A variation of [Frank's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45163192/678951), which stays closer to the original code snippet.

```
// foreach series --> load series details & seasons, foreach season --> load episodes
// when all requests are completed: do something

var requests = []

// e.g. series = [1]
series.forEach(function(seriesId) {
    requests.push(loadSeriesDetails(seriesId).then(function(data) {
        console.log("received details for series "+seriesId)
        // e.g. {id:1, title:"show 1"}
    }))
    requests.push(loadSeasons(seriesId).then(function (data) {
        console.log("received seasons for series "+seriesId+": ", data.seasons.length)
        // e.g. [{id:11, title:"season 1"}, {id:12, title:"season 2"}]
        var innerRequests = [] // <<<==============
        data.seasons.map(function(e) {return e.id}).forEach(function(seasonId) {
            innerRequests.push(loadEpisodes(seasonId).then(function (data) {
                console.log("received episodes for season "+seasonId+": ", data.episodes.length)
                // e.g.
                // season 11: [{id:111, title:"episode 1-1-1"}, {id:112, title:"episode 1-1-2"}, {id:113, title:"episode 1-1-3"}]
                // season 12: [{id:121, title:"episode 1-2-1"}, {id:122, title:"episode 1-2-2"}]
            }))
        })
        return $q.all(innerRequests) //  <<<==============
    }))
})

$q.all(requests).then(function(result) {
    console.log("*** all requests completed ***")
    console.log(result.length)
})
```